# How to change the app name and icon and retain the old project

Tags: android

i cant seem to find a way to change the app and icon without copying the project. i need it to be done within the app itself. any suggestions? ideas? thank you.

PS. someone told me to use symlink however it gets me so confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your application's name and icon without any problem in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Look for `android:icon` and `android:label` for changing name and icon in your manifest file.